# Subtracting rows to get the Row Echelon Form of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So I was taught that to get the Row Echelon Form of a matrix you have to add, subtract, or multiply the rows. So if I have a matrix like
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\1/2&1/2&-1/2\\1/2&-1/2&1/2\end{bmatrix}
And I want to make the last two rows in column one zero then could I subtract row two and three and change both rows or can I only change one row when I subtract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are allowed to do is to replace a certain row with the result of adding or subtracting a multiple of another row. In your example, you could naturally use row 1, so you replace R2 with R2-R1, and R3 with R3-R1:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\0&0&-2\\0&-2&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: So that's how I make the first two rows of column 1 all zeros? Then I could continue subtracting rows to get the RREF? Also that wasn't actually the question I was working on, that was just a sample question to know if I could do that. In the actual question you couldn't use row 1. I'll update my question with the actual question I'm working on.

Comment: It doesn't really matter which row you use. If you already have a $1$, you usually want to use that row. If you don't, you'll have to divide some row by a number to get a $1$.